# QGIS Plugins & Tools that replicate Select ArcPy Tools

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I developed a complex python application for road generation from GPS Devices that uses a few ArcPy Tools.

I want to try and replicate this Applications functionality using a freeware like PyQGIS instead of ArcPy, but in order to do this I need to find tools & plugins from QGIS that mimic the following tools:

- arcpy.da.SearchCursor
- arcpy.TableToTable_conversion
- arcpy.JoinField_management
- arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management
- arcpy.Delete_management
- arcpy.AddField_management
- arcpy.CalculateField_management
- arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management
- arcpy.CopyFeatures_management
- arcpy.PointsToLine_management,  QGIS Points to Path: http://spatialgalaxy.net/2011/12/30/qgis-plugin-of-the-week-points-to-paths/
- arcpy.Intersect_analysis
- arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis
- arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management
- arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management
- arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion
- arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question and here you are effectively asking at least 16 (one per tool).

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the tools you are looking for can be found in a single plugin - the **Processing** plugin. Importing this plugin from *PyQGIS* would allow you to call various tools (I am not an ArcGIS user so I am judging the tools you mentioned by their name and a quick search):

```
ArcGIS                            QGIS

arcpy.AddField_management         processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator",...) or processing.runalg("qgis:addfieldtoattributestable",...)
arcpy.CalculateField_management   processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator",...)
arcpy.Intersect_analysis          processing.runalg("qgis:intersection",...)
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis        processing.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation",...)
```

---

The [arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000) mentions that it creates a **temporary** layer which could be used as an input to another geoprocessing tool. When you use a processing tool in *PyQGIS*, you can use the term `None` as an output as this automatically creates the temporary file for that geoprocessing tool.

E.g.

```
outputs_1=processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", input_Layer, ............, None)
outputs_2=processing.runalg("qgis:fieldcalculator", outputs_1, ..........., Result)
```